# Scikit Learn Perceptron always returns same threshold for 1D vector and converges <10 iter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, perceptron

I am trying to run a simulation where the true population is 2 classes of normal distribution, both mean 0, standard deviation 4000.  I am attempting to use a perceptron to determine the relation of sample size to degree of overfitting.  However, the perceptron always converges after 6 iterations with a threshold of 0 despite a sample size of 10 per each class which you can clearly see should not have a threshold of 0.  Why is the threshold always 0?  Also, is there a better way to output the threshold than my code below?  I'm using perceptron because I want the simplest possible classifier - is there a simpler, easier classifier to use?  Note, Logistic Regression does seem to have thresholds other than 0 when used in exactly the same way.

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 0, 4000 # mean and standard deviation
pop_size=int(1e4)
p1 = (np.random.normal(mu, sigma, pop_size)) #1 million, pinky
p2 = (np.random.normal(mu, sigma, pop_size))

#take 10 samples of each group and plot on the same plot
def sample_pop(n):
    s1 = np.random.choice(p1, size=n, replace=False)
    s2 = np.random.choice(p2, size=n, replace=False)
    plt.subplot(211)
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(p1, 50, density=False, color='green', range=[-15000, 15000], histtype='bar', ec='black')
    plt.ylabel("n with Rebel Alliance")
    ymax=plt.gca().get_ylim()
    plt.plot(s1,[ymax]*n,'o',color='green')
    plt.subplot(212)
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(p2, 50, density=False, color = "red", range=[-15000, 15000], histtype='bar', ec='black')
    plt.xlabel("Midi Clorian Rate (The Force)")
    plt.ylabel("n with Dark Side")
    ymax=plt.gca().get_ylim()[1]
    plt.plot(s2,[ymax]*n,'x',color='red')
    plt.show()
    return s1,s2
n=10
s1,s2=sample_pop(n)

from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
clf = Perceptron()
s_all=np.hstack((s1,s2)).reshape(-1, 1)
y=np.hstack( ( [0]*len(s1), [1]*len(s2) ) )
clf.fit(s_all, y)

def plot1D(X, y, model,show=True):

    # adapted from https://github.com/tirthajyoti/Machine-Learning-with #Python/blob/master/Utilities/ML-Python-utils.py
    
    # Step size of the mesh. Decrease to increase the quality of the VQ.
    h = 0.2    # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].    

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = -.1,.1# X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))
    # Predictions to obtain the classification results
    #Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
    Z = model.predict(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1).reshape(-1, 1))
    dZ=np.diff(Z)
    print(Z[np.where(abs(dZ)>0)[0]]) #this is the threshold
    

    # Plotting
    if show:
        plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, np.vstack((Z,Z)), alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], np.array( [-.05]*len(X) ), c=y, alpha=0.8, edgecolor="k")
    plt.ylim(-.1,0)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_ticks([]) #set_visible(False)
    plt.xlabel('Midichlorian Rate (The Force)')
    if show:
        plt.show()
        
plot1D(s_all,y,clf)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
acc=accuracy_score(y, clf.predict(s_all))
acc
clf.n_iter_
```

PS - adding this image to answer Chris' comment below:
[image: 1000 draws of sample size "n" vs. distribution of accuracies using logistic regression (perceptron results are similar)]

Comment: You are expecting your model to classify random samples from two relatively equal distributions?  I'm assuming if you check your accuracy score, it should hover around 50% on repeated runs - as the model is basically guessing.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, if your sample size is small (such as this example of 10), the accuracy is not 50% even after 1000 runs.  Not sure why that is so, but it does converge as you increase sample size.  I have a good plot - but do you have any info on my question about why perceptron threshold is always 0 for a 1D vector but not so for logistic regression?  See my update to the original question for the plot

Comment: The two distributions are basically identical.  With a sample of 10 there is a change that you could randomly pick two samples that appear to be from different populations, which would cause your training to appear to be doing better than 50%.  Choosing a higher number of samples eliminates the random chance

Comment: Yes, that is true @Chris, but I still don't understand that over 1000 draws of sample 10 the mean of all draws is greater than the truth of 50% accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are facing is that since it is impossible for the perceptron to properly classify between two identical samples, the training loss will not improve no matter how many iterations you run - the model is randomly guessing.

This model has a default minimum number of iterations of 5, and will continue to iterate until the model accuracy improvement falls below the `tol` threshold.

In this case there is basically no chance of the model improving on the 6th iteration, because it's an impossible classification task - so it ends after the 6th iteration.

When the model is reduced to random guessing, I don't suspect you'd see the threshold change because there really isn't any threshold that would reliably improve the classification.

This behavior can be demonstrated by shifting the second distribution far outside the upper bounds of the first distribution, lowering the `tol` parameter, and increasing the `max_iter` parameter to a higher number.

This should give the model a fighting chance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 0, 4000 # mean and standard deviation
pop_size=int(1e4)
p1 = (np.random.normal(mu, sigma, pop_size)) #1 million, pinky
p2 = (np.random.normal(80000, 2000, pop_size))

#take 10 samples of each group and plot on the same plot
def sample_pop(n):
    s1 = np.random.choice(p1, size=n, replace=False)
    s2 = np.random.choice(p2, size=n, replace=False)
    plt.subplot(211)
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(p1, 50, density=False, color='green', range=[-15000, 15000], histtype='bar', ec='black')
    plt.ylabel("n with Rebel Alliance")
    ymax=plt.gca().get_ylim()
    plt.plot(s1,[ymax]*n,'o',color='green')
    plt.subplot(212)
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(p2, 50, density=False, color = "red", range=[-15000, 15000], histtype='bar', ec='black')
    plt.xlabel("Midi Clorian Rate (The Force)")
    plt.ylabel("n with Dark Side")
    ymax=plt.gca().get_ylim()[1]
    plt.plot(s2,[ymax]*n,'x',color='red')
    plt.show()
    return s1,s2
n=10
s1,s2=sample_pop(n)

from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
clf = Perceptron(tol=None, max_iter=20000)
s_all=np.hstack((s1,s2)).reshape(-1, 1)
y=np.hstack( ( [0]*len(s1), [1]*len(s2) ) )
clf.fit(s_all, y)

def plot1D(X, y, model,show=True):

    # adapted from https://github.com/tirthajyoti/Machine-Learning-with #Python/blob/master/Utilities/ML-Python-utils.py
    
    # Step size of the mesh. Decrease to increase the quality of the VQ.
    h = 0.2    # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].    

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = -.1,.1# X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))
    # Predictions to obtain the classification results
    #Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
    Z = model.predict(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1).reshape(-1, 1))
    dZ=np.diff(Z)
    print(Z[np.where(abs(dZ)>0)[0]]) #this is the threshold
    

    # Plotting
    if show:
        plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, np.vstack((Z,Z)), alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], np.array( [-.05]*len(X) ), c=y, alpha=0.8, edgecolor="k")
    plt.ylim(-.1,0)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_ticks([]) #set_visible(False)
    plt.xlabel('Midichlorian Rate (The Force)')
    if show:
        plt.show()
        
plot1D(s_all,y,clf)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
acc=accuracy_score(y, clf.predict(s_all))
acc
clf.n_iter_
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: interesting! - with 10 samples per class randomly drawn there should be many conditions where a threshold of 0 is not the best one.  in support of this, you can see in the plot I provide, in the n=10 case there are many accuracies > .5. Why is threshold always 0 but accuracy varies?  Your answer is good, and helpful, but there is a deeper answer to this.  Maybe too troubling to fully understand, but still interesting case of Perceptron. it is also interesting that this phenomenon of threshold always =0 is not the case for logistic regression, nor for a 2D perceptron (both with n=10 per class).